# Multiple line string, set on one line

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a 40 char string that's really 160 chars (4 lines of 40 char each).

I know about the can grow function, but would really like it all one one line.

**So instead of this: **

```
ABCDEFGH
IJKLMNOP
QRSTUVWX
YZ@@@@@@
```

**I'd like this: **

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@@@@@@@
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if the problem you are having is due to carriage returns or line feeds within the string, or is it simply wrapping the text to a new line because the length of the string exceeds the width of the field in your report?

Comment: All this data coming from the same field?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out yesterday, it was both. Doing a replace of chr10 and chr13 did the trick. Thanks!